# Repeating result in group where condition is met Big Query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

So I have a series of records and I want to know if it failed a test at any point and show it for the whole group

```
ID    Date     Test
A     1/2021   PASS
A     2/2021   PASS
A     3/2021   FAIL
A     4/2021   PASS
B     1/2021   PASS
B     2/2021   PASS
B     3/2021   PASS
B     4/2021   PASS
```

the desired result is

```
ID    Date     Test    EVERFAIL
A     1/2021   PASS    TRUE
A     2/2021   PASS    TRUE
A     3/2021   FAIL    TRUE
A     4/2021   PASS    TRUE
B     1/2021   PASS    FALSE
B     2/2021   PASS    FALSE
B     3/2021   PASS    FALSE
B     4/2021   PASS    FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

here is one way using window function:

```
select * , max(case when test ='Fail' then TRUE else FALSE end) over (partition by ID) GroupFail
from tablename
```